# How can I reliably detect if Flash was the originator of a request to a service?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, flash, http-headers, http-status-codes

I need to be able to detect if flash was the originator of a request to an ASP.NET service. The reason being that Flash is unable to process SOAP messages when the response status code is something other than 200. However, I allow exception to bubble up through our SOAP web services and as a result the status code for a SOAP server fault is 500.  Before Flash 10 I was able to check the referrer property and if it ended in .SWF I changed the status code to 200 so that our Flex application could process the SOAP messages appropriately.  But since the introduction of Flash 10 the referrer is no longer sent.  I would like to use the x-flash-version header, but it seems to only be sent when using IE, not FF.

Which brings me to my question:  How can I reliably detect if Flash was the originator of a request to a service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot **reliably** do this - after all, it could be a proxy, or someone may have snooped your Flash component's traffic to work out how to reuse your API without whatever restrictions the Flash version wouldn't have.

For a basic sanity check to differentiate the output, then you could just as simply add a flag to say "Flash API version please"; But with all HTTP communications, it is relatively trivial to fake whatever is required.

Comment: We decided that since we cannot reliable detect whether or not Flash was the originator of the request we have not spent any more energy trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about `http://domain.com/path/to/target?flash=true`? If all you are doing is changing the api or returning different errors you don't need a secure detection method.

Edit: Note, this is definitely not "reliable" but do you truly need a reliable detection method or one that merely works? This works, it's just not secure and if you need it to be secure you are doing something wrong because it's impossible to know what client is actually in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the user agent (but it could be faked), Flash uses something like "Adobe Flash"

Comment: Actually I have a flash film here doing a http request that provides the browser user agent.

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way (of the easy options presented) is to Regex match the referrer URL which will have .swf in it.

That would be a heck of a lot harder to spoof than a query string/form param of &flash=true. It's certainly hackable using hacker tools that can send false HTTP headers (referrer) but out of the options presented it takes the most effort.