# Determine Flash availability with JSP

Tags: flash, jsp, progressive-enhancement

Basically, I need to swap a JSP form with a Flash form should the user have it installed. I know there is a JavaScript option, but don't want to use this as that cuts out people who have Flash but not JavaScript.

Can't find anything for it online, I'm sure it can't be too difficult, any ideas? Some code would be jubbly if possible :)

Comment: Noted should be that JSP is a server side view technology which runs at the webserver, generates and sends HTML/CSS/JS to the client side. JSP does not run in the webbrowser at the client side and is therefore **unable** to determine flash availability. Your answer should really be sought in the JS corner or something else which runs in the webbrowser at the client side.

Comment: Yeah, was kind of hoping there was a way to request additional header information from the client though. Haven't spent much time reading this resource but I think it provides the SS option I was after:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/browser_hawk.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is the right way to do this.  The other alternative would be to attempt to launch a small flash app, and have the flash application request a redirect to something loading the full application.  If the initial flash app were small enough, it could be hidden or made invisible to the non-flash users.

But really, that's a bad idea, and you should just use Javascript to detect it.  The number of users with no Javascript but with Flash will be vanishingly small.

See also http://www.petefreitag.com/item/70.cfm and [How can I reliably detect if Flash was the originator of a request to a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730654/how-can-i-reliably-detect-if-flash-was-the-originator-of-a-request-to-a-service) for http header based approaches (as well as their limitations).

Comment: In the end JavaScript was used, despite creating a larger gap, just couldn't find a good enough server side solution (atleast one that was free)